# Can I drive up to the General Sherman (sequoia tree) general parking lot in a 30-foot RV and can I park it there during COVID-19 pandemic?

Tags: usa, covid-19, northern-california, yosemite

Can I drive up to the General Sherman (sequoia tree) parking lot in a 30-foot RV and can I park it there during COVID-19 pandemic? Looking to park while seeing the tree, not overnight.

I can't find much specific information online, and the parks' phone lines don't answer.

I even looked at the satellite photos and I do see some extra long parking spots, but it's not clear how big they are (apparently 2 car lengths).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [park website](https://www.nps.gov/seki/planyourvisit/conditions.htm), it says that parking facilities are still open:

> ## Facilities, services, and features that are open:
>
> [...]
>
> Roads and parking lots. Please park only in designated parking spaces. If a parking lot is full, refer to the park newspaper for other options.

The parks [veichles length restrictions](https://www.nps.gov/seki/planyourvisit/vehicle-restrictions.htm) page states that vehicles longer than *24 feet* are not advised.

You can not park next to the tree anyway unless you have a disability parking placard:

> Those with disability parking placards can park in a small lot along the edge of the Generals Highway. From there, a wheelchair-accessible trail leads a short distance to the tree. If you don't have a placard but can't manage the Main Trail, [during shuttle season](https://www.nps.gov/seki/planyourvisit/parktransit.htm) you can ride park shuttles (all are wheelchair accessible, and some kneel) to the accessible trail.

([source](https://www.nps.gov/seki/learn/nature/sherman.htm))

Comment: The vehicle length restrictions on the page you linked to only apply to certain roads in the park.  In particular, there are no length restrictions on Route 180, the road leading from Kings Canyon National Park to the Giant Forest Museum.

Comment: Note that the "shuttle season" link states that the shuttle will not be operating during Summer 2020.